# Translate Cyrillic to Latin with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert Cyrillic to Latin in T-SQL function?

**Update.** As I have not found anything ready on the web, I have asked the question and I have enclosed the answer to my question to share the code I have made. I marked the tick for knowledge sharing while asking question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Prezemyslaw Remin's initial answer as a point of reference for the replacements, here is a much better TVF version:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Cyrillic2Latin_tv (@String nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN(
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string,N'ый',N'y'),N'ЫЙ',N'Y'),N'а',N'a'),N'б',N'b'),N'в',N'v'),N'г',N'g'),N'д',N'd'),N'е',N'e'),N'ё',N'yo'),N'ж',N'zh'),N'з',N'z'),N'и',N'i'),N'й',N'y'),N'к',N'k'),N'л',N'l'),N'м',N'm'),N'н',N'n'),N'о',N'o'),N'п',N'p'),N'р',N'r'),N'с',N's'),N'т',N't'),N'у',N'u'),N'ф',N'f'),N'х',N'kh'),N'ц',N'c'),N'ч',N'ch'),N'ш',N'sh'),N'щ',N'shch'),N'ъ',N''),N'ы',N'y'),N'ь',N''),N'э',N'e'),N'ю',N'yu'),N'я',N'ya'),N'А',N'A'),N'Б',N'B'),N'В',N'V'),N'Г',N'G'),N'Д',N'D'),N'Е',N'E'),N'Ё',N'YO'),N'Ж',N'ZH'),N'З',N'Z'),N'И',N'I'),N'Й',N'Y'),N'К',N'K'),N'Л',N'L'),N'М',N'M'),N'Н',N'N'),N'О',N'O'),N'П',N'P'),N'Р',N'R'),N'С',N'S'),N'Т',N'T'),N'У',N'U'),N'Ф',N'F'),N'Х',N'KH'),N'Ц',N'C'),N'Ч',N'CH'),N'Ш',N'SH'),N'Щ',N'SHCH'),N'Ъ',N''),N'Ы',N'Y'),N'Ь',N''),N'Э',N'E'),N'Ю',N'YU'),N'Я',N'YA') AS NonCyrillic
);
```

*(Yes, I realise that is ugly to look at)*

As for a comparison, did a "quick" test of our production server at work (`_s` suffix function is the scaler and `_tv` is the Table-Value Function). The SQL:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

PRINT 'Using Scalar';
SELECT dbo.Cyrillic2Latin_s(BCM.[Name]) AS ReplacedName
FROM OpenGI..ic_yyclient BCM
WHERE BCM.[Name] IS NOT NULL;

PRINT 'Using TVF';
SELECT C2L.NonCyrillic AS ReplacedName
FROM OpenGI..ic_yyclient BCM
     CROSS APPLY dbo.Cyrillic2Latin_tv(BCM.[Name]) C2L
WHERE BCM.[Name] IS NOT NULL;


SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
```

And the Statistics:

```
Using Scalar

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(147548 rows affected)
Table 'icp_yyclient'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1449, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 78672 ms,  elapsed time = 84518 ms.
Using TVF

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(147548 rows affected)
Table 'icp_yyclient'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1449, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 36140 ms,  elapsed time = 36696 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

As you can see, although the scan and logical reads were the same, the processing time for 147,548 rows was significantly lower using the TVF (over 48 seconds faster). Thus, a TVF is a far superior answer to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution translating Cyrillic to Latin with `REPLACE` function.

```
create function dbo.Cyrillic2Latin (@string nvarchar(max)) 
returns nvarchar(max) as
begin

set @string = replace (@string, N'ый'       ,N'y')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ЫЙ'       ,N'Y')
set @string = replace (@string, N'а'        ,N'a')
set @string = replace (@string, N'б'        ,N'b')
set @string = replace (@string, N'в'        ,N'v')
set @string = replace (@string, N'г'        ,N'g')
set @string = replace (@string, N'д'        ,N'd')
set @string = replace (@string, N'е'        ,N'e')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ё'        ,N'yo')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ж'        ,N'zh')
set @string = replace (@string, N'з'        ,N'z')
set @string = replace (@string, N'и'        ,N'i')
set @string = replace (@string, N'й'        ,N'y')
set @string = replace (@string, N'к'        ,N'k')
set @string = replace (@string, N'л'        ,N'l')
set @string = replace (@string, N'м'        ,N'm')
set @string = replace (@string, N'н'        ,N'n')
set @string = replace (@string, N'о'        ,N'o')
set @string = replace (@string, N'п'        ,N'p')
set @string = replace (@string, N'р'        ,N'r')
set @string = replace (@string, N'с'        ,N's')
set @string = replace (@string, N'т'        ,N't')
set @string = replace (@string, N'у'        ,N'u')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ф'        ,N'f')
set @string = replace (@string, N'х'        ,N'kh')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ц'        ,N'c')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ч'        ,N'ch')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ш'        ,N'sh')
set @string = replace (@string, N'щ'        ,N'shch')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ъ'        ,N' ')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ы'        ,N'y')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ь'        ,N'')
set @string = replace (@string, N'э'        ,N'e')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ю'        ,N'yu')
set @string = replace (@string, N'я'        ,N'ya')
set @string = replace (@string, N'А'        ,N'A')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Б'        ,N'B')
set @string = replace (@string, N'В'        ,N'V')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Г'        ,N'G')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Д'        ,N'D')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Е'        ,N'E')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ё'        ,N'YO')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ж'        ,N'ZH')
set @string = replace (@string, N'З'        ,N'Z')
set @string = replace (@string, N'И'        ,N'I')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Й'        ,N'Y')
set @string = replace (@string, N'К'        ,N'K')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Л'        ,N'L')
set @string = replace (@string, N'М'        ,N'M')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Н'        ,N'N')
set @string = replace (@string, N'О'        ,N'O')
set @string = replace (@string, N'П'        ,N'P')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Р'        ,N'R')
set @string = replace (@string, N'С'        ,N'S')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Т'        ,N'T')
set @string = replace (@string, N'У'        ,N'U')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ф'        ,N'F')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Х'        ,N'KH')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ц'        ,N'C')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ч'        ,N'CH')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ш'        ,N'SH')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Щ'        ,N'SHCH')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ъ'        ,N'')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ы'        ,N'Y')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ь'        ,N'')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Э'        ,N'E')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ю'        ,N'YU')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Я'        ,N'YA')

return @String
end
```

Comment: Personally, I'd convert that to a Table-Value Function, rather than a Scalar. That volume of `REPLACE` isn't going to be quick, but on a large dataset, using a Scalar function is really going to slow things down.

Comment: I agree with this being a table valued function. If you make all those replaces nested this can be a single select statement which will run lightning fast.

Comment: I just noticed that the OP asked and then answered is own question in 1 minute... What is your reason behind this @PrzemyslawRemin ? Shameless Self Promotion? :)

Comment: @Larnu no. It took me some time to cook the code as I did not find anything on the web. There is an option to share your knowledge while asking question. I marked that tick. I just wanted to share it in case someone else had a similar need. I did not hoped for answers of improvement for which I am grateful with my upvote.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin No worries, just, as I hope you can appreciate, it's quite odd that someone would ask a question and then immediately answer it. :) Either way, yes the initial work is good, but could well be improved by changing it to a TVF, as you see in my answer. If you are using the function you provided above, I'd suggest giving the TVF version I created (from your initial code) a go. You'll find a nice speed improvement.

Comment: @Larnu while it may seem odd there are many threads about self answered questions on the meta site. There is nothing inherently wrong with the idea and I think this answer is a good example of that. However, the inline table valued function you posted is a better solution to this problem. I don't think this answer is worthy of a downvote by any means.

Comment: After the OP explained, I understood further. Unfortunately, you cannot invite after a period of time unless the Answerer edits the post (which I'm more than happy to do :) )

Answer (score 1):

There is function to convert both Cyrillic to Latin and opposite Latin to Cyrillic. It is adapted to Serbian language, but it should works if you change this variable table.

In Serbian language in some cases one cyrilic letters has two latin letters and all logic is in the function.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION ConvertCyrillicOrLatin (@string NVARCHAR(MAX), @convertType CHAR(1))  
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @i int  
    DECLARE @character NVARCHAR(1)
    DECLARE @twoCharacters NVARCHAR(2)
    DECLARE @convertedCharacter NVARCHAR(2)
    DECLARE @dest NVARCHAR(1000)  

    DECLARE @Alfabet table
    (
    sn INT,
    CyrillicLetter NVARCHAR(2),
    LatinLetter NVARCHAR(2)
    )

    INSERT INTO @Alfabet
    (sn, CyrillicLetter,LatinLetter)
    VALUES
    (1,N'а',N'a'),
    (2,N'б',N'b'),
    (3,N'в',N'v'),
    (4,N'г',N'g'),
    (5,N'д',N'd'),
    (6,N'ђ',N'đ'),
    (7,N'е',N'e'),
    (8,N'ж',N'ž'),
    (9,N'з',N'z'),
    (10,N'и',N'i'),
    (11,N'ј',N'j'),
    (12,N'к',N'k'),
    (13,N'л',N'l'),
    (14,N'љ',N'lj'),
    (15,N'м',N'm'),
    (16,N'н',N'n'),
    (17,N'њ',N'nj'),
    (18,N'о',N'o'),
    (19,N'п',N'p'),
    (20,N'р',N'r'),
    (21,N'с',N's'),
    (22,N'т',N't'),
    (23,N'ћ',N'ć'),
    (24,N'у',N'u'),
    (25,N'ф',N'f'),
    (26,N'х',N'h'),
    (27,N'ц',N'c'),
    (28,N'ч',N'č'),
    (29,N'џ',N'dž'),
    (30,N'ш',N'š')
    
    SET @dest = ''
    SET @i = 1;  
    --PROCENT MAKE PROBLEM IF PASS TO THE FUNCtiON
    DECLARE @PercentReplacement VARCHAR(4)
    SET @PercentReplacement = '####'
    DECLARE @src NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLACE((SELECT N''+@string),'%',@PercentReplacement)
    DECLARE @isLowoer BIT 
    WHILE (@i <= LEN(@src))  
    BEGIN  
    SET @character = SUBSTRING(@src, @i, 1)
    SET @twoCharacters = SUBSTRING(@src, @i, 2)
    
    --IF IT IS CONVERTING TO CYRILLIC
    IF UPPER(@convertType) = 'C' 
    BEGIN
        SET @convertedCharacter =(SELECT N'' + CyrillicLetter FROM @Alfabet WHERE N'' + LatinLetter LIKE N'' + LOWER(@twoCharacters))
        IF @convertedCharacter IS NULL
            SET @convertedCharacter =(SELECT N'' + CyrillicLetter FROM @Alfabet WHERE N'' + LatinLetter LIKE N'' + LOWER(@Character))
        ELSE
            SET @i = @i + 1
    END
    ELSE IF UPPER(@convertType) = 'L' 
    BEGIN
        SET @convertedCharacter =(SELECT N'' + LatinLetter FROM @Alfabet WHERE N'' + CyrillicLetter LIKE N'' + LOWER(@Character))
    END

    SET @isLowoer = (SELECT CASE WHEN N'' + UNICODE(@character) LIKE N'' + UNICODE(LOWER(@character))  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    --IF IT IS NOT LETTER, SET THAT CHARACTER
    IF @convertedCharacter IS NULL
    SET @dest =  @dest + @Character
    ELSE
    SET @dest =  @dest + CASE WHEN @isLowoer = 0 THEN UPPER(@convertedCharacter) ELSE @convertedCharacter END
    

    SET @i = @i + 1  
    END
    RETURN REPLACE(@dest,@PercentReplacement,'%')  
    
END
```

To call this function just pass text and convert type, C for Cyrillic and L for Latin.

```
   SELECT dbo.ConvertCyrillicOrLatin(N'ThIS IS SOME,! tEst nj dž aaa 100%','c')
   OUTPUT: ТхИС ИС СОМЕ,! тЕст њ џ ааа 100%
   SELECT dbo.ConvertCyrillicOrLatin(N'ТхИС ИС СОМЕ,! тЕст њ џ ааа 100%','L')
   OUTPUT: ThIS IS SOME,! tEst nj dž aaa 100%
```